# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to change the `visibility` attribute of a menu item from the `onReceive` method of the `android Broadcast class`, but I keep getting the above `title error` even when it works for another `intent` using the same method:

My `Broadcast class` code:

```
 /**
     * Use this to catch the intent sent from the JobSchedulerService class
     */
    public BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public IBinder peekService(Context myContext, Intent service) {
            return super.peekService(myContext, service);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //TODO: Remove
            Toast.makeText(context, "Intent detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (intent.getAction().equals(MY_INTENT)) {

                //TODO: Remove
                Toast.makeText(context, "MY_INTENT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                MenuItem refreshMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh);
                refreshMenuItem.setVisible(true);
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader(CRYPTOCURRENCY_LOADER_ID, null, HomeActivity.this);
           }    


            if (intent.getAction().equals(CONNECTION_INTENT)) {

                status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

                //TODO: Remove
                Toast.makeText(context, "CONNECT_INTENT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                MenuItem netMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_network_available);
                MenuItem nonetMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_network_absent);


                // Check and notify user of network status
                if (Objects.equals(status, "Wifi enabled") || Objects.equals(status, "Mobile data enabled")) {

                   netMenuItem.setVisible(true);
                   nonetMenuItem.setVisible(false);

                } else {

                   netMenuItem.setVisible(false);
                   nonetMenuItem.setVisible(true);

                }

            }
        }
    };
```

The `NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context)` code:

```
public class NetworkUtil {

    public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return TYPE_WIFI;

            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return TYPE_MOBILE;
        }
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }

    public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
        int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        String status = null;
        if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
            status = "Wifi enabled";
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            status = "Mobile data enabled";
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            status = "Not connected to Internet";
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

The `onCreateMenuOption` method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

        //inflate the menu options from the menu xml file
        //This add menu items to the app bar
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.network_available, menu);
        this.menu = menu;

        if (menu != null) {

            if (isConnected()) {
                // Let user know the status of the device network
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_network_available).setVisible(true);
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_network_absent).setVisible(false);
            } else {
                // Let user know the status of the device network
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_network_available).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.menu_network_absent).setVisible(true);
            }


        }


        return true;
    }
```

The `menu xml` file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/progress"
        android:title="data Refresh"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_network_available"
        android:title="@string/network_avalable"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="always" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_network_absent"
        android:title="@string/network_absent"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not precisely sure why it's working for you in one place but not in another, but I can say that what you're doing doesn't follow (what I consider to be) best practices.

Rather than modify the `Menu` directly from your broadcast, it would be better to call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`. You'd also override `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)` in your activity, and perform the changes there. Maybe something like this:

```
// in the broadcast receiver
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
    online = (Objects.equals(status, "Wifi enabled") || Objects.equals(status, "Mobile data enabled"));
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    ...
}


// in the activity
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem netMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_network_available);
    MenuItem nonetMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_network_absent);

    netMenuItem.setVisible(online);
    nonetMenuItem.setVisible(!online);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am learning android so please forgive my lack of use of `best practice` and thank you for the answer let me implement it and see how it plays out

Comment: Great played out nice